# How to call an MVC3 controller action using PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, http

I am calling an MVC3 controller action (JsonResult) from a console application.  To make the call I am using a System.Net.Http.HttpClient and the PostAsJsonAsync method.

In the PostAsJsonAsync method I am passing a small poco instance.

It all works great apart for one thing.

***My problem is that I cannot pick up the poco instance in the call to the the MVC3 controller action.***  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Here's the code:

**Calling code in console application:**

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50285/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var user = new HashedUser { UserName = "userName", PasswordHash = "abcdef".GetHashCode() };

        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("app/test", user).Result;

        var txt = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
```

**Receiving Code in MVC3 project**

```
public class AppController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult Test(HashedUser json)
    {
        // Problem: json is always a new instance 
        // of HashedUser and not the one passed in 
        // from the call to this controller action.

        return Json("qqq ppp 777 888" + json.UserName);
    }
}

public class HashedUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize and send your POCO as JSon object. Use Newtonsoft.Json to do that. Here's some samples:

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing